# how to extract class type from a jitclass and specify it alone

Tags: python, numba, jit

I have a jitclass say `weather` and save one of its attribute `att = weather.class_type.instance_type` to use in another jit function to specify its output style.

```
out_style = Tuple.from_types((ListType(att)))
@jit([out_style(nb.int64, nb.int64)], nopython=True)
def new_function():
    ......
```

This attribute is printed as below.

```
27725c129d0<_data:array(float64, 2d, A),_colmap:DictType[unicode_type,int64]<iv=None>,date0:datetime64[M],_tdelta:timedelta64[M]>
```

Now I want to remove this jitclass, still want to manually specify this attribute and use it. I see there are four data types, `array(float64, 2d, A)`, `DictType[unicode_type,int64]`, `datetime64[M]`, and `timedelta64[M]`

I declare it this way, however, error is reported as below.

```
out_style = Tuple.from_types((ListType(nb.types.Array(nb.float64, 2, 'A'), DictType(nb.types.unicode_type, bb2), nb.types.NPDatetime('M'), nb.types.NPTimedelta('M')))


TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Please help to fix this issue. Thanks.

I'm not sure I understand it correctly. `ListType()` can contain only one argument. In my case, I added four in `ListType()`. It causes the error. Here type of `att` is `classinstancetype`. Since `jitclass` is removed as previously mentioned, which data type would be a good alternative, tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nb.types.Tuple.from_types` takes a list in parameter that should contain each type of the tuple. For example:

```py
nb.types.Tuple.from_types([
    nb.types.ListType(nb.types.int32), 
    nb.types.float64, 
    nb.types.int64
])
```

This is a type of tuple containing 3 elements: a list of 32-bit integers, a 64-bit float and a 64-bit integer.

Based on your code, I guess you want this:

```py
out_style = nb.types.Tuple.from_types([
    nb.types.ListType(nb.float64[:,:]), 
    nb.types.DictType(nb.types.unicode_type, bb2), 
    nb.types.NPDatetime('M'), 
    nb.types.NPTimedelta('M')
])
```

Comment: Thanks It makes sense. One question is what 'A' means in 'nb.types.Array(nb.float64, 2, 'A')'. I realize another question, as mentioned, 'att' is used to store jitclass type. Actually, I can copy it from definition of '@jitclass'. However, the 'out_style' is a 'tuple', not a class. So my question is using tuple to replace class. How do you feel this approach in numba module. I can define a main function to mimic class, and use tuple to store all attributes and return this tuple. Say one attribute is function, should I define it inside the main function with '@njit' decorator?

Comment: one more thing is the difference between tuple approach and list approach. In the previous jitclass, one attribute is a function to update another attribute. If I use a main function to replace the jitclass and return tuple as output, there will be no way to update that attribute. Do you think converting tuple to list, update and then change back to tuple will work? or I can directly return a list instead. Thanks!

Comment: 'A' means the array may not be contiguous while 'C' means the last dimension of the array is contiguous. In my opinion, it is simpler to work with basic types and functions. First because of the Python object model which is not great but also because of the experimental support of Numba which is not very well documented and not very flexible either.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your second point. In pure-Python, tuple and list are similar except that tuples have immutable items AFAIK. In Numba, this is different: tuples are like a structure few items of (possibly) different types and a list is a sequence of the same type. You cannot switch from one to another easily in most cases (unlike with Python).

Comment: Thanks. @Jérôme Richard I think I have seen 'B', does it mean other dimension of an array is contiguous? You are right, in numba, tuple can contain different types of data and list and dictionary can only contain the same type of data. so tuple is a better choice in my case. I'm have problems with updating tuple, since some attributes will be updated. I have to update nested tuple. Need to figure it out.

Comment: AFAIK, 'B' does not exist in that case. Only one dimension can be contiguous in memory (the one with a stride equal to the number of bytes in each array item). I think the mutation of a structured heterogeneous type is a good reason to use objects. I did not think about this case. Generally, I use many arguments in that case (simpler & flexible), but it can make sense to regroup them in a given object type (especially when there is a lot of them or several function use the same argument).